# Can we rename cloud storage files using dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to rename cloud storage files using dataflow program . Is it possible to do that ? if yes then how .

Answer (score 1):

While the Apache Beam SDK does not contain a ready-made `PTransform` for renaming files, there's nothing preventing you from doing it yourself - pipelines can contain arbitrary code in `DoFn`'s, and you could either use the standard [Google Cloud Storage Java APIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java), or more conveniently, using Beam's `FileSystems` API. For example:

```java
class RenameFn extends DoFn<KV<String, String>, Void> {
  @ProcessElement
  public void process(ProcessContext c) {
    ResourceId src = FileSystems.matchNewResource(c.element().getKey());
    ResourceId dest = FileSystems.matchNewResource(c.element().getValue());
    FileSystems.rename(Arrays.asList(src), Arrays.asList(dest));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually i am really new to dataflow so could you please explain what should be the key and value. Is it filename ?

Comment: Key is the source filename, value is destination filename. Keep in mind that I have not tested this code, I just used it as an illustration of how to use FileSystems.rename() API and how to convert from String to ResourceId that the FileSystems API takes.